# Remove a custom element definition Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

I'm building an app that stores custom elements in back-end. The front-end receives the HTML(and other) code of the custom elemnts via `<link>` tags. Something like this:

```
<link href="/serverurl/custom-table-widget.html" rel="import">
```

The problem is that a user can upload an updated custom element with some code changes to the back-end in the same app. I would like to display the updated custom elements without reloading the page.

What I'm doing now when a user uploads an updated custom element is:

- I remove the `<link>` tag of the custom element from the header.
- I re-import the custom element via a link tag as an attempt to redefine it.

When I do that, this error shows up in the console and nothing gets updated:
[image]

It's probably because I'm trying to define an element that was previously already defined. But what could be the workaround for this? Is there any way to un-define the element?

Comment: Show us some fiddle or code what have you done so far.

Comment: Check if it's already defined if you can't, use define it in try-catch block and if error message is this name already has beed defined, just skip it.

Comment: Define should be used only once per CustomElement so why use definition more than once?

Comment: @Zydnar To update an element with new code from the server.

Comment: looking at duplicate question if you can't undefine component, workaround might be changing name eg. componentName-v2

Comment: Sorry for spam, I think you take it from the wrong side - I don't know how much changes, but you can change code inside in other way eg. via attributes. If an attribute changes, so does shadow dom inside custom element according to your definition.

Comment: @gfeis Custom elements currently cannot be undefined. If your objective is to update your component dynamically, you'd have to refresh the page to re-register the component with the new code.